# Difference between asp controls and html with runat=server atribute

Tags: asp.net, runat

Could you explain me the difference between  controls and html components with the "runat=server" attribute. What is best practice to use it? Thanks.

Comment: I assum you refer to <asp:Label> stuff and <span runat="server">?  If so why did you tag it asp-classic? They are both asp.net features...

Comment: you are right. i saw a lot of places in my project where <asp:label> and <span with runat="server" atribute used. That is why i try to understand why it was written this way.

Comment: in my opinion <span> and <asp:label> tags are equal between each other. Which tags we should use depend on developers, is not?

Comment: the main reason to understand is that if i want to show the text on a page i can use some html tags and part of the controls of VS. i understand that i can use both suggestions but if i prefer use html instead of asp component i can use html. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

```
<span runat="server" id="myspan"> </span>
```

maps to the [GenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) class defined in System.Web.UI.HtmlControls. From it's [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.aspx) description:

> The System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace contains classes that allow
>   you to create HTML server controls on a Web Forms page. HTML server
>   controls run on the server and map directly to standard HTML tags
>   supported by most browsers. This allows you to programmatically
>   control the HTML elements on a Web Forms page.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="asplabel"></asp:Label>
```

maps to the [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx) class in System.Web.UI.WebControls. From it's [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.aspx) description

> The System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace contains classes that allow
>   you to create Web server controls on a Web page. Web server controls
>   run on the server and include form controls such as buttons and text
>   boxes. They also include special-purpose controls such as a calendar.
>   Because Web server controls run on the server, you can
>   programmatically control these elements. Although Web server controls
>   are rendered as HTML, their object model does not necessarily reflect
>   HTML syntax.
>
> The System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace contains classes that are
>   rendered as HTML tags, such as the TextBox control and the ListBox
>   control. The namespace also contains classes that are not rendered on
>   the Web page, but support data operations, such as the SqlDataSource
>   and ObjectDataSource classes. Other controls, such as the GridView and
>   DetailsView controls, support data display and editing. The WebControl
>   class serves as the base class for many of the classes in the
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace.

Basically the controls from the WebControl namespace gives you more features where the design aim was to mimic VB6 forms as closely as possible to make the transition (back asnd forth) between winclient and webclient programming seamlessly.

I personally tend to use controls from the WebControls namespace as much as possible and only fallback to the HtmlConttols if I need behavior that is not availbale on a WebControl and not overrideable.

A [blog](http://odetocode.com/articles/348.aspx) from K. Scot Allen on the same topic

Comment: From the blog i understand that we should use asp controls because it gives us a geranty that everything will be shown well on a clientside. Another thing is that we can extend asp control for the button and another controls of the asp.

Answer (score 0):

Server controls are tags that are understood by the server.

There are three kinds of server controls:
HTML Server Controls- Traditional HTML tags
Web Server Controls - New ASP.NET tags
Validation Server Controls - For input validation

HTML Server Control:

HTML elements in ASP.NET files are, by default, treated as text. To make these elements programmable, add a runat="server" attribute to the HTML element.

Example:

```
<form runat="server">
......
</form>
```

Web Server Controls:

Web server controls are special ASP.NET tags understood by the server.

Like HTML server controls, Web server controls are also created on the server and they require a runat="server" attribute to work. However, Web server controls do not necessarily map to any existing HTML elements and they may represent more complex elements.

Example:

```
<asp:Button ID="but" runat="server"/>
```

Validation Server Controls:

Validation server controls are used to validate user-input. If the user-input does not pass validation, it will display an error message to the user.

Example:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="req1" runat="server" ControlToValidator="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="please enter proper details"/>
```